# Menu blinking is not working

Tags: html, css

I have four links in menu. i want to give a blinking effect on contact us menu. It is working fine when i load this code first time. After click on other menu ( apart from Contact us) it stopped blinking. Please help me to solve this issue. Here is my code

```html
<html>
<head>
<style>
ul{list-style:none;}
ul li a{width:100px;text-align:center; padding-left: 20px;float:left;padding-right:20px; font-size:20px;text-decoration:none;}
/*ul .about a{background-color:grey;border:1px solid darkgrey;}
ul .about
{
-webkit-animation:flash 0.5s linear infinite;
-moz-animation:flash 0.5s linear infinite;
animation:flash 0.5s linear infinite;
}
@-webkit-keyframes flash
{
80%{opacity:1;}
80%{opacity:0;}
}
@-moz-keyframes flash
{
80%{opacity:1;}
80%{opacity:0;}
}
@keyframes flash
{
80%{opacity:1;}
80%{opacity:0;}
} -->*/

/*Blink with multiple color
.blinker{*/
ul .contact a{
font-family: muli,arial,sans-serif;
font-size: 18px;
color:#565656;
animation: changecolor 1.5s infinite;
-moz-animation: changecolor 1.5s infinite; 
-webkit-animation: changecolor 1.5s infinite;
-ms-animation: changecolor 1.5s infinite;
}
@keyframes changecolor
{
50%   {color: red;}
10%  {color: #565656;}
}
/* Mozilla Browser */
@-moz-keyframes changecolor 
{50%   {color: red;}
50%  {color: #565656;}
}
/* WebKit browser Safari and Chrome */
@-webkit-keyframes changecolor 
{
50%   {color: red;}
20%  {color: #565656;}
}
/* IE 9,10*/
@-ms-keyframes changecolor 
{
50%   {color: red;}
20%  {color: #565656;}
}

</style>
</head>
<body>
<ul>
<li class="home"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
<li class="about"><a href="#">About</a></li>
<li class="Contact"><a href="#">Contact us</a></li>
</ul>
<div class="blinker">SUBSCRIBE</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please, fix your code first. You have an error in your CSS.

Comment: And even more please, don't do this.    
There are other less annoying ways to make a link stand out. You could differentiate using a different background-colour, or using a different font (-size, -weight, -…).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `animation` for the blinking effects as you've already used,

Just use [**wow animation**](http://mynameismatthieu.com/WOW) for better effects and which add extra functionality and options for the `animation`.

write its `js` as:

```
       wow = new WOW({
          boxClass:     'wow',      // default
          animateClass: 'animated', // default
          offset:       0,          // default
          mobile:       true,       // default
          live:         true        // default
        })
        wow.init();
```

Change your `CSS` as:

```
ul li.contact a{
     font-family: muli,arial,sans-serif;
     font-size: 18px;
     color:#565656;
     animation-iteration-count: infinite;
     -o-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
     -moz-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
     -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
   }


  @-webkit-keyframes changecolor {
      0%   {  color: #f00;  }
      100% {   color:#f9a933;}
  }

  @-moz-keyframes changecolor {
     0%   {  color: #f00;  }
    100% {   color:#f9a933;}
  }

  @-o-keyframes changecolor {
      0%   {  color: #f00;  }
      100% {   color:#f9a933;}
  }

  @keyframes changecolor {
      0%   {  color: #f00;  }
       100% {   color:#f9a933;}
   }


  .changecolor {
        -webkit-animation-name: changecolor;
        -moz-animation-name: changecolor;
        -o-animation-name: changecolor;
        animation-name: changecolor;
  }
```

and your `DOM` as:

```
<li class="contact"><a class="wow changecolor"  data-wow-duration="0.3s" data-wow-delay="0.8s"  href="#">Contact us</a></li>
```

I've created a [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/vivekkupadhyay/0pppp7ga/1)  too.

Answer (score 0):

your selector dose not select the correct html element.

I changed it from `ul li.contact a` to `ul li a`.

```css
ul{list-style:none;}
ul li a{width:100px;text-align:center; padding-left: 20px;float:left;padding-right:20px; font-size:20px;text-decoration:none;}

ul li a{
font-family: muli,arial,sans-serif;
font-size: 18px;
color:#565656;
animation: changecolor 1.5s infinite;
-moz-animation: changecolor 1.5s infinite; 
-webkit-animation: changecolor 1.5s infinite;
-ms-animation: changecolor 1.5s infinite;
}
@keyframes changecolor { 50%   {color: red;} 10%  {color: #565656;}}
@-moz-keyframes changecolor { 50%   {color: red;} 10%  {color: #565656;}}
@-webkit-keyframes changecolor { 50%   {color: red;} 10%  {color: #565656;}}
@-ms-keyframes changecolor { 50%   {color: red;} 10%  {color: #565656;}}
```

```html
<ul>
<li class="home"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
<li class="about"><a href="#">About</a></li>
<li class="Contact"><a href="#">Contact us</a></li>
</ul>
<div class="blinker">SUBSCRIBE</div>
```